# Prolog: I need to loop through all the "items" in my "Facts" database, but just take the first one and finish

Tags: prolog

As the title says, when you get the first done and use it, then you should continue with the next one, until you print them all, but since it takes that it is true, the first does not consider the others.

Need to take "le", "lc", "ru" and "rv".

Facts:

```
    invar( xx, 0,0, 255,255 ).
    invar( pphi, -180,0, 180,255 ).

    f_p( le, xx, [ 0,255, 30,255, 96,0, 255,0 ] ).
    f_p( lc, xx, [ 0,0, 76,0, 102,255, 127,0, 255,0 ] ).
    f_p( ru, pphi, [ -180,0, -97,0, -63,255, -28,0, 180,0 ] ).
    f_p( rv, pphi, [ -180,0, -47,0, -23,255, 0,0, 180,0 ] ).
```

Code that uses the fact base:

```
impresionPruebaGeneral(FD):-
     writeln(FD,'pruebaGeneral(X):-'),
     invar(Invar,_,_,_,_),
     f_p(F,_,_),
     write(FD,'prueba'),write(FD,F),writeln(FD,'(X),'),!.
```

Impression it makes:

```
    pruebaGeneral(X):-
    pruebale(X),
```

Desired print:

```
    pruebaGeneral(X):-
    pruebale(X),
    pruebalc(X),
    pruebaru(X),
    pruebarv(X),
```

It doesn't matter that it doesn't have the period "." in the end, that takes care of another predicate after

Comment: Get rid of the cut, what is it doing? Use a forall/2 loop to iterate over all solutions and print as the side effect.

Comment: Which Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: @User9213 But what condition should I put? because the fact base can change, I can't say as a condition that "rv" is the last

Comment: @TA_intern I am using the prolog version: SWI-Prolog version (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4). I guess basic prologue, I've been using it for a month. I just need to fix this that I consult for a TP. But I can't find how.

Comment: What is a TP? How do you consult for it?

Comment: [I need TP for my...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHv2dIM3t9I)